# Caterpillar identification: Peru

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

[image: Caterpillar from Amazon Rainforest - Tamshiyacu Tahuayo area - Peru]

Could you please help me identify this caterpillar (Amazon rainforest, Peru)?
Is it a species of Megalopygidae???

Comment: Did you take this picture? If so, could you provide more information about where it was found (e.g., on the ground, on a tree, etc.).

Comment: Yes - On the trunc of a living tree - During the day - Tamshiyacu Tahuayo Regional Conservation Area.

Comment: It resembles a Puss mouth or flannel moth caterpillar. The adult moth is beautiful and the bristles of the caterpillar are very irritating.. It does indeed belong to the Megalopygidae

Answer (score 2):

It is an pink flannelmoth because there is no other insect which ressembles it

[image: Pink flannelmoth]

Usually pinkflannelmoths have orange coloured centers

Comment: The proposition that something is something because it looks like it is completely falacious. I could say that a person is an ape because they look alike. Perhaps it is an undiscovered species?

Comment: But with just one photo from the top view you can't expect the answer right

Comment: I do agree with your there

Comment: Please provide supporting facts.. simply saying, "I couldn't find anything better" isn't the best logic to use.